# Why does the informationschema bring back malformed resuts with a like operator?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-like, information-schema

im having trouble with the below script:-

```
USE master

DECLARE @COMPANY CHAR(3)
declare @createdatabase char(50)
declare @fromdatabase char (50)
declare @sql1 char(100)
declare @logicaldatabasename Char(100)
declare @logicaldatabaselog char (100)

set @fromdatabase = 'a'
set @createdatabase = 'b'

SET @COMPANY = 'PUK'

;with q as (
SELECT [name] [logical_name]
FROM sys.[master_files]
WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID(@fromdatabase))
select @logicaldatabasename = q.[logical_name]
from q
where q.[logical_name] not like '%log%'
;with q as (
SELECT [name] [logical_name]
FROM sys.[master_files]
WHERE [database_id] = DB_ID(@fromdatabase))
select @logicaldatabaselog = q.[logical_name]
from q
where q.[logical_name] like '%log%'

select @logicaldatabasename AS LOGICALDATABASENAME, @logicaldatabaselog AS LOGICALDATABSELOG

--BACKUP DATABASE @fromdatabase
--TO DISK = '\folder\'+@fromdatabase+'.bak'
Set @sql1 = 'CREATE DATABASE '+@createdatabase
Exec (@sql1)
RESTORE DATABASE @createdatabase FROM DISK = '\flder\DANTEST.bak' 
WITH MOVE @logicaldatabasename TO 'folder\b.mdf',
MOVE @logicaldatabaselog TO '\folder\b_log.ldf',
REPLACE 
select * from sys.master_files where database_id = db_id(@createdatabase)
;
go
use b
go
;
DECLARE cCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR


#NAME?
SELECT
  IST.TABLE_NAME AS tblName
FROM
  nhba_a.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IST
WHERE RIGHT(IST.TABLE_NAME,3) <> 'PUK' AND IST.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and ist.TABLE_NAME like '%_%'

ORDER BY IST.TABLE_NAME

--
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(255)
--
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @crlf CHAR(2)

SET @crlf = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)

OPEN cCursor
FETCH cCursor
INTO @tblName

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
if @tblname like '%_%'
SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@tblName);
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

  FETCH cCursor
  INTO @tblName
END
```

when using this:-

```
SELECT
  IST.TABLE_NAME AS tblName
FROM
  nhba_a.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES IST
WHERE RIGHT(IST.TABLE_NAME,3) <> 'PUK' AND IST.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and ist.TABLE_NAME like '%_%'

ORDER BY IST.TABLE_NAME
```

I get tables without a _ but I have searched for tables with only _.

could anyone explain why its not coming back with the correct results and what sql is actually doing in the background?

I have tried varies ways to bring up the correct results but have not able to find out what the problem is because the logic is sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `LIKE` operator the underscore `_` actually referees to any ONE character. It means `_` has a special meaning with the `LIKE` operator.

If you want to return table names where there is an  underscore then you need to escape the underscore in your where clause, something like...

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%\_%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Or you can also use the square brackets to escape the underscore without using the keyword `ESCAPE`

```
WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%[_]%'
```

Comment: wow, thanks for that piece of knowledge, the escape worked but the brackets did not.